# Find the fundamental period of $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x-1)+f(x+1)=f(x)$

Find the fundamental period of $f(x)$ satisfying the above functional equation.

I try to solve this problem by sub $x=x+1$ and adding but it doesn't help me

Comment: Why must it have a period?

Comment: @copper.hat they give me this question to find fundamental period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that $f$ is non zero, as otherwise the periods can be taken
to be arbitrarily small.

If you fix $x$ then the values at $f(x)$ and $f(x-1)$ completely define $f$ on the
set $\mathbb{Z}+\{x\}$, since if we let $y_n = f(x+n)$, the values satisfy
the difference equation $y_{n+1} = y_n-y_{n-1}$, subject to
$y_0 = f(x), y_{-1} = f(x-1)$. Solving this difference equation shows that
any non zero solution has period 6.

Since $x$ was arbitrary, the above holds true for every $x$, and since $f$
is assumed non constant, it is true for some $x$, hence $f$ has period 6.

The above shows that the value of $f$ on $[0,2)$ completely define $f$.